# 'Photo' object is not iterable error in django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have created a page when the staff click on the view button, it should redirect them to the view page, but I am getting this error 'Photo' object is not iterable as shown in the picture below. How do I solve this error?

This is how my page looks like with the view button
[image]

'Photo' object is not iterable error
[image]

views.py

```
def view(request, pk):

    alldescription = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)

    return render(request, 'view.html', {'alldescription': alldescription})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('adminpage/', views.admin, name='adminpage'),
    path('customer/', views.customer, name='customer'),
    path('logistic/', views.logistic, name='logistic'),
    path('forget/', views.forget, name='forget'),
    path('changepassword/', views.changepassword, name='changepassword'),

    path('newblock/', views.newblock, name='newblock'),
    path('quote/', views.quote, name='quote'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('adminprofile/', views.adminprofile, name='adminprofile'),

    path('', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('allstaff/', views.allstaff, name='allstaff'),
    path('updatestaff', views.updatestaff, name='updatestaff'),
    path('delete/<int:id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('deletephoto/<int:id>/', views.deletephoto, name='deletephoto'),

    path('update/<int:id>/', views.update, name='update'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register_view, name='register'),
    path('edit-register/', views.edit_register_view, name='edit_register'),
    path('edit_profile/', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    path('ReceptionUnserviceable/', views.ReceptionUnserviceable, name='ReceptionUnserviceable'),
    path('success', views.success, name='success'),
    path('logisticprofile', views.logisticprofile, name='logisticprofile'),
    path('viewreception/', views.viewreception, name='viewreception'),
    path('view/<str:pk>/', views.view, name='view'),
    path('outgoingLRU/', views.outgoingLRU, name='outgoingLRU'),

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

viewreception.html

```
{% extends "logisticbase.html" %}
{% block content %}
<style>
table {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border:solid black 1px;
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
}

td, th {
    border-left:solid black 1px;
    border-top:solid black 1px;
}

th {
    border-top: none;
}

td:first-child, th:first-child {
     border-left: none;
}


h4{color: #006E33;}

</style>


   <div style="padding-left:16px">
     <br>
       <h4>Reception Unserviceable  </h4>
       <p>To delete, click on the delete button.</p>
 <div class="form-block">

  </tr>
         {% for Photo in alldescription %}
     <div class="col-md-9">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-5">
                 <div class="card my-2">
                     <img class="image-thumbail" src="/media/{{Photo.image}}"  width="250px">
                     <br>

                     <div class="card-body">
                         <small>Customer Name: {{Photo.customername}}</small>
                         <br>
                         <small>Date and Time: {{Photo.datetime}}</small>
                     </div>
                     <form action="{% url 'view' Photo.id %}" method="post">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" style="width: 460px">View</button>
                      </form>

                     <br>
                      <form action="{% url 'deletephoto' Photo.id %}" method="post">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="width: 460px">Delete</button>
                      </form>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>




{% endfor %}
```

view.html

```
{% extends "logisticbase.html" %}
{% block content %}
<style>


</style>


   <div style="padding-left:16px">
     <br>
       <h4>Reception Unserviceable  </h4>
 <div class="form-block">


  </tr>
         {% for Photo in alldescription %}
           <img src="/media/{{Photo.image}}" width="250px">
         {% endfor %}


 </div>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't return a queryset but instead s single instance in your view (indicated by the `get` method), thus it is not iterable.

```
def view(request, pk):

    alldescription = Photo.objects.get(id=pk) 

    return render(request, 'view.html', {'alldescription': alldescription})
```

That's why you cant iterate in your template.

Just use

```
<img src="/media/{{ alldescription.image }}" width="250px">
```

and return the other loops in `viewreception.html` and `logisticbase.html` templates as well.

Comment: I put that but it still give me the same error

Comment: @Shadowwalker see updated answer

Comment: sorry, which loop you talking about in the viewreception.html?

Comment: @Shadowwalker </tr>
         {% for Photo in alldescription %}
     <div class="col-md-9">
         <div class="row">

Comment: my image cannot be display at my view.html page

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
Photo.objects.get(id=pk)
```

But [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) returns you a single item. In your template, you try to iterate through this one item. It is not possible. So this is the reason you get an error while rendering related template.

You should use in your template by removing for-loop:

```
<img src="/media/{{ alldescription.Photo.image }}" width="250px">
```

Comment: i try put that and i still got the same error

Comment: You don't clear out all for-loops. I see one looop in viewreception.html.

Comment: I remove but i have an error: NoReverseMatch at /viewreception/ Reverse for 'view' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$'] –

Comment: You have another error in somewhere else. Please edit your question, and specify where you encounter with this error.

Comment: nvm, that error is now fix, but my image cannot be display at my view.html page

Comment: We cannot know exactly where the error is. You should share your model etc. And I think your initial problem is solved, so you should create a new question. Then, I could help you there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69279665/how-do-i-display-image-in-my-view-page-django